# jQuery.data() and cross browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I want to use the jQuery.data() method to attach data to a DOM object as an alternative to storing it in an attribute.

The method seems perfectly suited to my needs, but in the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/), there's this line:

> Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.

Does this mean the method won't work in IE? In my testing the method works fine with IE8 on Windows 7, but I don't want to run into issues with any browsers.

Thanks.

Comment: they are referring to XML docs, if you are not planning to use it on XML docs you are fine

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Notice the

> ... for setting data on XML documents ...

As long as you're working with HTML I think you should be fine

Comment: Thanks. Seems like a dumb question now, but I needed to make sure.

Comment: How about XHTML? Isn't that an XML document?